# Ошибки после выполения

Tags: java

Задача на java: написать программу, что будет выводить все дни твоего рождения на 5 лет вперед двумя способами: просто все в main, что изи, и с помощью ООП. И во втором случае после выполнения, причем правильного, выводится куча ошибок. С ООП я пока не слишком разобрался, и пока очень сложно понять, в чем собственно причина

```
package birthday;

public class Dispatcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Birthday bd = Controller.bd(2019, 5,13);
    }
}

package birthday;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Controller {
    public static Birthday bd(int y, int m, int d){
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d MMMM yyyy");
        while (y<=2024) {
            gc.set(y, m, d);
            Date date = gc.getTime();
            System.out.println(df.format(gc.getTime()));
            y++;
        }
        return (bd(y,m,d));
    }
}

package birthday;

public class Birthday {
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    public Birthday(int y, int m, int d){
        this.year = y;
        this.month = m;
        this.day = d;
    }
}
```

Comment: ООП это когда есть объект типа(читай класса) и у него есть свойство день рождение. И чтобы не усложнять мы можем наделить этого человека поведением(читай методом) сказать нам все его дни рождения на N лет вперед. То есть этот метод возьмет свойство день рождения генерирует список дат на следующие N лет и вернет вызывающему методу

Comment: Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Позднее если будет время напишу пример. Но задачу стоит озаглавивить по-другому...В заголовке нужно указывать какую проблему надо решить. Или текст возникающей ошибки или помоч в создании класса в стиле ООП

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код работает в принципе неправильно. Дни недели, которые он выводит в консоль, не соответствуют датам. А ошибка, которую вы получаете, возникает потому, что ваш метод bd вызывает сам себя return (bd(y,m,d)) и это происходит бесконечно, в связи с чем у вас заканчивается память. 
А в целом есть принцип YAGNI под названием KISS, что означает "сделай это проще". Эта задача решается из коробки и очень просто.
А еще обратите внимание на пакет java.time он появился в java 8 и заменил java.util.Date (это вообще позор java, как по мне). Посему настоятельно рекомендуется пользоваться именно java.time.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

class Dispatcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getDirhday(2019, 5, 13, 5);
    }

    private static void getDirhday(int y, int m, int d, int count) {
        for (int i = y; i < y+count+1; i++) 
            System.out.println(LocalDate.of(i, m, d) + " : " + 
                    LocalDate.of(i, m, d).getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.forLanguageTag("ru")));
    }

}
```

Comment: А где тут ООП? Парень эти вопросы только изучает потому и косячит с рекурсией которая скорей всего получилась в следствии переноса кода, а не по его желанию. Но вот научите меня-дурака плз где дни недели не соответствуют данным? Почему так происходит? gc.set(y, m, d); бажит? Ваш же код ни коем образом не демонстрирует ООП, он ничем не отличается от main варианта

Comment: ну тогда давайте 2*2 считать с помощью ООП. есть огромное количество примеров, которые очень хорошо ложатся на ООП парадигму. зачем искусственно накручивать сложность тривиальной задачи? про причину ошибки я написал в ответе. рассказал про пакет java.time, который имеет непосредственное отношение к данному примеру, показал, как решить данную задачу. а притягивать за уши ООП из-за того, что кто-то учиться и взял неудачный пример... могу только  еще раз повторить - KISS никто не отменял.

Comment: прочитайте пожалуйста текст вопроса. Применить подход ООП было одним из условий задачи... Я так понимаю это упражнение для закрепления материала.

Comment: И вы пожалуйста меня извините за мою невнимательность, но причины критики "Дни недели, которые он выводит в консоль, не соответствуют датам." я так и не заметил. Потому и переспросил в первом моем коментарии что вызвало эту критику? gc.set(y, m, d)?

Comment: Controller.bd(2019, 5, 13); - вызов метода в даном случае соответствует 2019 году 5 месяцу 13 числу. консоль выводит четверг, 13 июня 2019. насколько я понимаю, 5 месяц - май, а 13 мая 2019 года - совсем не четверг. почему в примере 5 месяц оказывается июнем для меня загадка...

Comment: Ваша загадка развенчивается документацией к данному методу. 
month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)

Comment: разумеется, если бы мы говорили про метод класса GregorianCalendar, при использовании которого я полезу в документацию и посмотрю, как он работает. но мы говорим про вызов собственноручно написанного метода. в связи с чем очень желательно , чтобы инженерная система имела ожидаемое поведение, а не повторяла всю "кривизну" библиотек, которые использует этот метод. очень желательно писать код методов (их названия, сигнатуры и т.д.) таким образом, чтобы их использование было интуитивно понятным и не требовалось изучать весь исходный код, чтобы понять, почему и как это работает.

Comment: вот теперь ваша мысль до меня дошла. Наверное я не так смышлен как хотелось бы, по этому не понял что говоря о "Дни недели...не соответствуют датам" вы имели ввиду, что в своем API надо скрывать косяки чужого API. Которые в свою очередь связанны с тем, что номер месяца удобней отчитывать с 1, а не с 0. Теперь у меня выстроилась четкая логическая цепочка вашего посыла о хорошем API, с чем я полностью согласен.

Comment: в любом случае считаю обсуждение полезным. спасибо